# Vue component working main Vue instance but not in Vue Router component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have set up a Laravel / Vue app with the main element (#app) for my app in my welcome.blade.php file.
Then I have app.js file in which I initiate my Vue instance. And then there's my routes.js and MyComponent.vue files.

In MyComponnent.vue I am trying to load vue-winwheel. But I keep getting this warning:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

And the component won't load. If I use directly in my welcome.blade.php file it does load, but in the wrong place of course.

I did register VueWinwheel globally (tested both VueWinwheel and vue-winwheel). 
Anyone have any ideas what I'm missing?

**app.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import VueWinwheel from 'vue-winwheel/vue-winwheel'
import routes from './routes';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(VueWinwheel);

require('./bootstrap');

let app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 router: new VueRouter(routes),
 components: {
  VueWinwheel
 }
});
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ asset('images/FavIcon-64.png') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">

        <title>My App with VueWinwheel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app" class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <transition name="slideFade" mode="out-in">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </transition>
            <vue-winwheel /> <!-- This one does work -->
        </div>
        
        <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**MyComponent.vue**

```html
<template>
 <section class="winwheel-section">
  <vue-winwheel /> <!-- This one does not work and makes the warning show in console -->
 </section>
</template>

<script>
 module.exports = {
  data: function(){
   return {
    
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

**router.js**

```js
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent';

export default{
 mode: 'history',

 routes: [
  {
   path: '/',
   component: MyComponent,
   name: 'MyComponent'
  }
 ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried what @AbdulAzeez Olanrewaju suggested (and tried it before). But this gave me an error in my npm vue watch terminal:

> "export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found in '-!../../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--4-0!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./Spin.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&'

Comment: I think you need to add `import VueWinwheel from 'vue-winwheel/vue-winwheel'` in the vue file you want to use it

Comment: @AbdulAzeezOlanrewaju, I have tried that, gives me this compiling error:
"export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found in '-!../../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--4-0!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./Spin.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&'

Comment: I actually think it would be the best solution, but I can't seem to import anything in my Vue files.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and change

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: new VueRouter(routes),
    components: {
        VueWinwheel
    }
});
```

to

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: new VueRouter(routes),
    components: {
        'vue-winwheel': VueWinwheel
    }
});
```

Also i do not think you need to use the Vue.use(VueWinWheel);

Comment: No change unfortunately. Tried it with and without the Vue.use,

Comment: Yes. It is the same warning as before: 
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <vue-winwheel> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.

I could not import Winwheel inside my MyComponent.vue because I used module.exports.
When I use export default it did work.

So:

```js
<!-- This -->
<script>
 export default {
  data: function(){
   return {
    
   }
  }
 }
</script>

<!-- Instead of this -->
<script>
 module.exports = {
  data: function(){
   return {
    
   }
  }
 }
</script>

<!-- Note that I also remove the = after module.exports
```